# C: Special characters in strings defined within inline assembly

Tags: string, gcc, inline-assembly

I realize that it's a bit off the beaten path, but I have an AVR with an interrupt table where most of the interrupts are not used. I've shaved off quite a bit of code space for a bootloader by putting strings to be printed instead of the unused jump instructions. It's an ATmega1280 which can't really reach its own string constants when in the bootloader (would need 17 bits of address, and avr-gcc only keeps 16 bits). So I'm using a puts that takes in a 32 bit integer instead of the usual "char *".

So far, so good. But I wanted an escaped newline in one of the strings. 
This works, but is ugly:

```
".ascii \"first line\""
".byte 0x5c"
".byte 0x0a"
".asciz \"second line\""
```

This works, but throws up a warning:

```
".asciz \"first line\\\\\nsecond line\""
```

As in, both produce the expected text "first line\\nsecond line" in the binary.

The warning is "dualloader.s:159: Warning: unterminated string; newline inserted"

Yes, I inserted a newline. That was sort of the point. But in the temporary .s generated, I see

```
"first line\\
second line"
```

rather than what I hoped for:

```
"first line\\\nsecond line"
```

This is obviously the source of the warning. A funny effect is if I reduce the number of backslashes so:

```
".asciz \"first line\\\nsecond line\""
```

The .s will now contain:

```
"first line\
second line"
```

Which at first seems correct. But the binary ends up containing the text "first line\nsecond line", as in a backslash followed by the character 'n'.

I know this is not very pretty, and I know I could do all of it in assembly OR go all C and just let the code size grow to where I need to double the allocated flash size for the bootloader. But by now I'm getting very intrigued as to whether .ascii and .asciz  is even MEANT to work in inline assembly using GCC. Especially the backslash followed by 'n' result baffled me to no end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
".asciz \"first line\\\\\\nsecond line\""
```

Given that, the compiler ought to emit this:

```
.asciz "first line\\\nsecond line"
```

Which ought to be emitted in the binary as:

```
first line\<LF>second line
```

Comment: Uh. Facepalm. Thanks.